# How to programmatically change Facebook posts visibility to "public" on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, visibility, public, privacy

Would like to change the default visibility of app and posts in Facebook from "Friends" to "Public" programmatically on iOS. Is there any example code for this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `defaultAudience` Property .

Most applications use FBSessionDefaultAudienceNone here, only specifying an audience when using reauthorize to request publish permissions.

There are other option to set is,

***FBSessionDefaultAudienceNone***:
No audience needed; this value is useful for cases where data will only be read from Facebook.

***FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe***:
Indicates that only the user is able to see posts made by the application.

***FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends***:
Indicates that the user's friends are able to see posts made by the application.

***FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone***:
Indicates that all Facebook users are able to see posts made by the application.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:completionHandler: is deprecated.

Comment: @Hughes: try with `requestNewPublishPermissions: defaultAudience:completionHandler:` method.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/) that you can setup the privacy of the post at creation time, but you cannot edit it.

Also, per facebook's developer TOS and Privacy Policy, unless what you are doing [changing the default privacy of a post] is specifically authorized each time by the user, it'd be breaking terms of service and immediately get your app shut down. Facebook takes privacy very, very seriously.